# Not Clear How to Account for a Specific Test Case in My Function that Compares Strings Looking for Differences

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, conditional-statements

Write a function called singleline_diff_format that takes two single line strings and the index of the first difference and will generate a formatted string that will allow a user to clearly see where the first difference between two lines is located. A user is likely going to want to see where the difference is in the context of the lines, not just see a number. Your function will return a three-line string that looks as follows:

```
#abcd

#==^

#abef
```

The format of these three lines is:

1) The complete first line.

2) A separator line that consists of repeated equal signs ("=") up until the first difference. A "^" symbol indicates the position of the first difference.

3) The complete second line.

If either line contains a newline or carriage return character ("\n" or "\r") then the function returns an empty string (since the lines are not single lines and the output format will not make sense to a person reading it).

If the index is not a valid index that could indicate the position of the first difference of the two input lines, the function should also return an empty string (again because the output would not make sense otherwise). It must, therefore, be between 0 and the length of the shorter line. Note that you do not need to check whether the index actually identifies the correct location of the first difference, as that should have been computed correctly prior to calling this function.

I am able to write the function, and I used an if-else setup to evaluate if the index doesn't equal -1 and if the lines contain any '\r' or '\n' characters. I then have it printing out the result like in the instructions above. If it doesn't meet those cases, then the function returns an empty string.

```
def singleline_diff_format(line1, line2, idx):
    """
    Inputs:
      line1 - first single line string
      line2 - second single line string
      idx   - index at which to indicate difference
    Output:
      Returns a three line formatted string showing the location
      of the first difference between line1 and line2.

      If either input line contains a newline or carriage return,
      then returns an empty string.

      If idx is not a valid index, then returns an empty string.
    """
    if idx != -1 and "\n" not in line1 and "\n" not in line2 and "\r" not in line1 and "\r" not in line2:
        difference = line1 + "\n" + "=" * idx + "^" + "\n" + line2 + "\n"
        return difference  
    else:
        return ""
```

The problem I am running into is how to address "If the index is not a valid index that could indicate the position of the first difference of the two input lines, the function should also return an empty string (again because the output would not make sense otherwise). It must therefore be between 0 and the length of the shorter line."

```
print(singleline_diff_format('abcdefg', 'abc', 5)) #should return empty string
```

Instead, I get this:

```
abcdefg

===^

abc
```

As it stands right now, my if conditional is pretty long. I am not sure of a good way to account for if the index is bigger than the length of the shorter line in my conditional. I have two questions.

1) Is there a way to condense down my current conditional into a more elegant statement?

2) How do I account for a scenario where the index can exceed the length of a shorter line? I have a function (see below) that might help with that. Should I invoke it, and if so, how do I invoke it for this case?

Potential useful function

```
IDENTICAL = -1

def singleline_diff(line1, line2):
    """
    Inputs:
      line1 - first single line string
      line2 - second single line string
    Output:
      Returns the index where the first difference between
      line1 and line2 occurs.

      Returns IDENTICAL if the two lines are the same.
    """
    if len(line1) > len(line2):
      i = 0 
      for i in range(len(line2)):
        if line1[i] == line2[i]:
          i += 1
        elif line1[i] != line2[i]:
          return i
      return len(line2)
    elif len(line1) < len(line2):
      i = 0
      for i in range(len(line1)):
        if line1[i] == line2[i]:
          i += 1
        elif line1[i] != line2[i]:
          return i
      return len(line1)
    else: #Condition where the lengths of the strings are equal
      i = 0
      for i in range(len(line1)):
        if line1[i] == line2[i]:
          i += 1
        elif line1[i] != line2[i]:
          return i
      return IDENTICAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to compound *all* of your special conditions into a single check.  Your program will be *much* easier to read if you handle those separately.  Also, use temporary variables to avoid calling functions repeatedly.  For starters ...

```
len1 = len(line1)
len2 = len(line2)
empty = ""
```

Now, your problem condition is simply

```
# Check for invalid index: too long or negative
if idx >= min(line1, line2) or idx < 0:
    return empty
```

Continuing ...

```
# Check for return chars
both_line = line1 + line2
nl = '\n'
ret = '\r'
if nl in both_line or ret in both_line:
    return empty
```

---

You can also simplify your difference checking.  `zip` will let you make nice character pairs from your two strings; `enumerate` will let you iterate through the pairs *and* a loop index.  In the first two examples below, there is no difference within the range of the shorter string, so there's no output.

```
def diff(line1, line2):

    for idx, pair in enumerate(zip(line1, line2)):
        if pair[0] != pair[1]:
            print(idx, pair)

diff("abc", "abc") 
diff("abc", "abcd")
diff("abz", "abc")
diff("abc", "qbc")
```

Output:

```
2 ('z', 'c')
0 ('a', 'q')
```

I'll leave the application as an exercise for the student.  :-)